# Publishing my first android app Supported Android devices 0 on playstore

Tags: android, android-studio

I have developed my first android app in Android Studio. I have developed a simple flashLight app. It is working well on multiple devices, but when I publish it to the playstore there is a compatibility issue. Please help me out.

> Supported Android devices = 0 Devices

Mainfest.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.dhairya.fastflashlight">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"></uses-permission>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.Camera"></uses-feature>

    <supports-screens
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="720"
        android:resizeable="true"
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true" />


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_flash"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name="dc.suvy.dhairya.fastflashlight.Flashlight">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
```

Build Gradle

```
    android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "dc.suvy.dhairya.fastflashlight"
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 9
        versionCode 2
        versionName '2.0'
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'commons-io:commons-io:2.4'
}
```

Comment: your targetSdkVersion is 9. I think this is the main issue.

Comment: how can i fix it should i do it to 23 ?@KrupalShah

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
    minSdkVersion 9
    targetSdkVersion 9
```

To

```
    minSdkVersion 9
    targetSdkVersion 23
```

Also cross check if you really need these (just remove it if you have no good reason for keeping it):

```
    <supports-screens
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="720"
    android:resizeable="true"
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true" />
```

Comment: i have tried it but still it is showing Suported Devices 0 ? please help @AndroidMechanic

Comment: Clean and regenerate signed apk. And did you do both the changes I suggested?

Comment: yes i have done both changes @AndroidMechanic `android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "dc.suvy.dhairya.fastflashlight"
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 2
        versionName '2.0'
    } `

Comment: Removed supports-screens?

Comment: Yes i have removed Support-Screens

Comment: One more thing. Change build tools versions to match compile SDK. Use 23.0.1

Comment: `android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "dc.suvy.dhairya.fastflashlight"
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 2
        versionName '2.0'
    }`

Comment: When you upload the new apk, dev console will show differences in permissions and features (of this is an update and not a new app). Share a screen shot of that with all sections expanded.

Comment: [link](https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/?ui=2&ik=a840b616b4&view=att&th=155bc9b601126060&attid=0.1&disp=safe&realattid=f_iq9vcivy0&zw) Here is the screenshot

Comment: 404.. You have some gmail link there

Comment: I have published the APK before but when it went live on app store it showed 0 devices supported now i am uploading new APK by changing version name to 2.0

Comment: [link](http://www.gadgetsdesk.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/Untitled.png) Try this screenshot link

Comment: What should i do now can you help me please its my first project ?

Comment: Although this is not a place to ask for debugging help, you may upload your codes somewhere and share the link. I'll take a look

Comment: Ok I'll do it as soon as possible

Comment: [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_03jP805l5qVkFmMy00dVJCVUk) here is a link of my project please take a look at it

Comment: i have tried removing this line and now it supports 12447 devices but app not starting after removing these lines   `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"></uses-permission>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.Camera" > </uses-feature>`

Answer (score 0):

Your **target SDK should always be the latest SDK version** you can use. So just change your Build gradle to.

```
   minSdkVersion 9
   targetSdkVersion 23
```

Comment: I have changed it but no change still Supported Devices 0 `android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "dc.suvy.dhairya.fastflashlight"
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 2
        versionName '2.0'
    }`   @Ken Ratanachai S.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the reason for this is a third party library that you have referenced. If you can find which one is it and if you can remove it you can solve the problem.

try removing

```
compile 'commons-io:commons-io:2.4'
```